# Passing in arguments to a ruby class upon initializing in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I've created this Vehicle class and a car Subclass

```
class Vehicle
  def initialize(year)
    @model_year = year
  end
  def get_model_year()
    @model_year
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize
    @wheels = 4
  end
  def wheels
    @wheels
  end
end
```

Now Im trying to figure out how to create a new car variable with .new while passing in the model year in as an argument

```
my_car = Car.new(2000)
my_car.get_model_year => Expecting 2000
```

Comment: You still need to define the `year` parameter in `Car`'s initialize method. Then use  the `super` keyword to forward _all_ passed arguments to the template method in `Vehicle`. The `get_model_year` will now work using normal inheritance rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `super` keyword to invoke super class in the `initialize` method.

```
class Vehicle
  def initialize(year)
    @model_year = year
  end

  def get_model_year()
    @model_year
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize year
    super
    @wheels = 4
  end

  def wheels
    @wheels
  end
end

my_car = Car.new(2000)
my_car.get_model_year => 2000
```

Comment: BTW you don't need to pass args to `super` explicitly in this case, just typing `super` would be enough.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
class Vehicle
  def initialize(year)
    @model_year = year
  end

  def get_model_year
    @model_year
  end
end


class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize *args
    super(args[0])
    @wheels = 4
  end

def wheels
    @wheels
  end
end

my_car = Car.new(2000)
puts my_car.get_model_year
```

you need to read up on ruby basics,

call the `super` method in your child initializer, it just calls the same method in your parent class, so if you call super from method A in child class, it calls A method in parent class

* is just a splat operator to accept multiple numbers of arguments

Comment: I don't see the point of giving the programmer possibility to pass multiple arguments to `Car#initialize`.

Comment: apart from model_year if he needs to he can pass other details like brand_name, cost, type etc...

Comment: Yeah, if he does, he will add more parameters, I guess. It's unnecessary by now.

Comment: I don't see how its unnecessary, OP seems to be new to ruby so I was just trying to help and he might need to use that, I don't see why you need to point out that its unnecessary for me to give some more info

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, it is really a bad answer that deserves some more downvote, doesn't answer the question :D :D

Comment: It's not mine, calm down. :)

Comment: While it may seem unnecessary to some, I do appreciate the foresight and thank you for your help.